# Integrating audio player which support both mozilla and IE

Tags: php, javascript

I want to integrate (php) a audio player which supports both mozilla and internet explorer, with a player image on the webpage that should contain all the functionalities forward, rewind, pause, volume...

Answer (score 1):

Audio isn't something you want to process with PHP (unless you want the *server* to play some music in the server room)

Check out [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/). It is a nice jQuery-based audio player with nice browser support. Check out [this demo](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/0.2.5/demo-02.htm) in particular.